# ggplot2 for two y-axes using geom_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data consisting two groups along time. I would like to plot the actual value and the sum of the values of the group in each year on two y-axes. But it showed an error "Error in p - lim2[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHz3b.png): argument of binary operator is not numerical".

```
year <- c("2000", "2000", "2000", "2000", "2025", "2025", "2025", "2025", "2050", "2050", "2050", "2050")
group <- c("a","a","b","b","a","a","b","b","a","a","b","b")
value <- c(1,1.5,2,2.5,2,2.2,3,3.3,4,4.4,5,5.3)
d <- as.data.frame(cbind(year, group, value))


y1.lim <- c(0, 15)
y2.lim <- c(0, 25)

variable_scaler <- function(p, lim1, lim2){
  to_zero <- p-lim2[1]
  y1_range <- lim1[2]-lim1[1]
  y2_range <- lim2[2]-lim2[1]
  scaled <- to_zero*y1_range/y2_range
  from_zero <- scaled + lim1[1]
  return(from_zero)
}

axis_scaler <- function(p, lim1, lim2){
  to_zero <- p-lim1[1]
  y1_range <- lim1[2]-lim1[1]
  y2_range <- lim2[2]-lim2[1]
  scaled <- to_zero*y2_range/y1_range
  from_zero <- scaled + lim2[1]
  return(from_zero)
}

pd <- d %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value ,color = group, group = interaction(year, group)))+
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width=0.75))+
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.1, width=0.75)+
  geom_line(aes(y = variable_scaler(stat_summary(fun = "sum"),y1.lim, y2.lim)))+
              scale_y_continuous(limit=y1.lim,  
                                 breaks=c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),  
                                 sec.axis=sec_axis(
                                   ~(axis_scaler(., y1.lim, y2.lim)), 
                                   breaks=c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20), 
                                   name='sum')  
              )

plot(pd)
```

------update--------

I added the column showing the sum of the values grouped by year and group. Then, I may succeeded to plot two kinds of values on two y-axes. I tried to geom_point() into geom_line(), but it didn't work. How can I draw the lines between the summed values (geom_pointted value)?

```
pd <- d %>%
  group_by(year, group)%>%
  mutate(sum = sum(value))%>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = year, y = value ,color = group, group = interaction(year, group)),
               alpha = 0.1, width=0.75)+
  geom_point(aes(x = year, group = interaction(year,group), 
                y = variable_scaler(sum, y1.lim, y2.lim),color = group),position = position_dodge(width=0.75))+
              scale_y_continuous(limit=y1.lim,  
                                 breaks=c(0, 5, 10, 15),  
                                 sec.axis=sec_axis(
                                   ~(axis_scaler(., y1.lim, y2.lim)), 
                                   breaks=c(0,5, 10,15, 20, 25), 
                                   name='sum'))  
   geom_line(aes(x = year, group = interaction(year,group), 
                 y = variable_scaler(sum, y1.lim, y2.lim),color = group))
              

plot(pd)
```

[image]

Comment: Well, first off, don't do `d <- as.data.frame(cbind(year, group, value))`, instead do `d <- data.frame(year, group, value)` because the `cbind` will convert everything to character.  Then it's not clear what you are doing with `variable_scaler(stat_summary(fun = "sum"),y1.lim, y2.lim)`. Why are you trying to pass `stat_summary` in there? That returns a `geom` which you cannot do mathmatical operations on in the `variable_scaler` function.  Maybe you just wanted `aes(y = variable_scaler(value,y1.lim, y2.lim))`? It's not clear to me what the desired result is.

Comment: Try with `stat_summary(aes(group = group), fun = function(x) variable_scaler(sum(x),y1.lim, y2.lim), geom = "line")`

Comment: Thank you very much for commenting. @MrFlick I added some tries and an image of the results.

Comment: @stefan I tried the code you suggested, it is getting closer to my image, but the value of geom_line() is just the value, not "sum" of them.